# Android cancel async task called multi times

Tags: java, android, listview, android-asynctask

How can I cancel an async task that is called multi times this code below will explain what I mean:

Now this is my class that is extends asyncTask

```
private class sendMessage extends AsyncTask<Integer,Void,Long>{

    public sendMessage() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Long aLong) {
        super.onPostExecute(aLong);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(Long aLong) {
        super.onCancelled(aLong);

        //task canceled will delete it from sqlite
        sqlite.deleteMessage(aLong);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
    }

    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(Integer... integers) {

          Long id sqlite.insertMessage("blabalbla");
    }
}
```

Now in android I have an listView of users and every user item have button send.
When the user click on send its show loading on the listView item meanning sending.

This will explain more:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


        new sendMessage().excute(user_id);

        //sendMessage_task =  new sendMessage();
        //sendMessage_task.excute(user_id); 

        }
       });
```

Now its easy to cancel this AsyncTask if I have refrence to the class

```
sendMessage_task.cancel(true);
```

But what if user click on many items in listView "send button" the refrence will fail because its refrence to one object and when I cancel the task its will cancel last one only.

> user click on multi item in listView send button

```
   sendMessage_task =  new sendMessage();
   sendMessage_task.excute(user_id); 

   sendMessage_task =  new sendMessage();
   sendMessage_task.excute(user_id); 

   sendMessage_task =  new sendMessage();
   sendMessage_task.excute(user_id);
```

and when I cancel of Course its will cancel last one only

> I just thinking about save refrence of object in arrayList or some where else 
>   but I have activity rotation problem will remove them all

Comment: It's very vague where and when you would want to cancel the task, but you yourself said that the first problem is you don't store any reference to the running task so there's nothing to cancel. Solve that problem, then ask about the rest.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov cancel will excute when click on send button again ..
yes iam not store refrence because its many items in listView for which itsm i will store refrence and why i post question there if i done that ?

Comment: The fact that there are several items doesn't mean you should store nothing. Instead you should decide what relation the task and list item have, then replicate that relation withing the storage for running tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Your cancel method should looks like

```
private void cancel() {
    if (sendMessage_task == null) {
        return;
    }
    sendMessage_task.cancel(true);
    sendMessage_task = null;
}
```

Then call cancel on every "send" event.

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    cancel();
    sendMessage_task =  new sendMessage();
    sendMessage_task.excute(user_id); 

    }
   });
```

Comment: ok i know this but i said user called this class many time and want to cancel them all again the refrence will be for last item only and its will not cancel all

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncTask` instances can be executed only once.

You can use one reference

```
private AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Long> task = null;
```

and recreate it multiple times in your `listener` after canceling the previous one

In your listener:

```
if (task != null) {
    task.cancel(true);
}
task = new MyAsyncTask();
task.execute(...);
```

Comment: ok i know this but i said user called this class many time

and want to cancel them all again the refrence will be for last item only and its will not cancel all

Comment: @smsmsmsm you mean that you want to have many `AsyncTask` instances that run in parallel and be able to cancel them all?

Comment: yes thats it ... its an activity for forward message to users 
and you click on send button and send message to many user maybe you want to cancel some of messgae you sent thats the idea

Answer (score 0):

Create a mapping from *user ID* to `AsyncTask`:

```
Map<Integer, AsyncTask> tasks = new HashMap<>(); // assuming user ID is Integer. Adjust if not.
```

When the user clicks on an item, put the user's ID and the AsyncTask you create to the map: `tasks.put(userId, theNewlyCreatedTask)`.

When the user clicks *cancel*, find the corresponding task by user ID and `cancel()`, something like this:

```
AsyncTask myTask = tasks.get(userId);
if (myTask != null) {
    myTask.cancel();
}
```